# Detecting when tab item is clicked in Storyboard

Tags: ios

Is there any way to programmatically check in the main view when a tab item created in Storyboard is clicked?

I tried putting the following where my UITabBarController  class is:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController  {

    NSLog(@"Gets here");
}
```

But no luck.

Comment: Did you set the delegate for your UITabBarController?

Comment: Yes I set it in the MainViewController which is initialized when the app opens. When I put that method there it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to link your tabBar item to your .m file (With split views of your storyboard and .m file, with right click on your item). 
Then, name the method and do what you want to do in it.